# Django management command: [Errno 61] Connection refused

Tags: django, django-manage.py

I have written a Django custom management command—call it `command.py`. When I run it using `manage.py command`, I get the following error:

```
error: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

The command doesn't import anything other than the standard `BaseCommand` and `CommandError`, as well as my project-specific models. It doesn't make (or shouldn't be making) any SMTP connections, but just in case, I added the following line to `settings.py`. I get the same error.

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

---

Details: this is essentially what the command file contains.

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from my_app.models import MyModel

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for piece in MyModel.objects.all():
            piece.field = 'value'
            piece.save()
```

Comment: there's a `--traceback` parameter for `manage.py`, try to use it if you'll get some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. What does `piece.save()` do? Is your model trying to send an email on save?
2. What's your logging setup? Is there an error in your code which your app is trying to email you about?

Comment: `piece.save()` shouldn't be doing anything other than saving the model.

Comment: Your second comment may well be the case.

Comment: To clarify since I stumbled across this googling for the same problem, which cropped up again: it was indeed the logging that caused the error. The functionality provided by the management command still succeeded.